# If document exist update it, otherwise create the exact doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `doc` which is a document I retrieve from an external database and I want to create a document or update already created document in my `collection` in my database.

We can simply see if there is a document with same `_id` in my `collection`. But for deciding if we need to update our document in the `collection` we have `update` property in the document, so we can compare the `update` date of the `doc` from external database to `update` date of our document in our `collection`, right?

Here is a prototype of what we want:

```
const documentExist = await db.collection.findById(doc._id);

if (documentExist) {

  const exactDocument = documentExist.update.getTime() === doc.update.getTime();

  if (!exactDocument) {
    // overwite documentExist with doc because doc is updated
  }

} else {
  // add the doc to collection exactly as it is, with same _id etc..
  const newDoc = new db.collection(doc);
  await newDoc.save();
}
```

How would you do this?

As you see in the prototype I first check to see if there is the document in `collection`. if not create it, if there is a document with same `_id` to doc, then decide if it's needed to update or not?

Comment: Have you checked out [upsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/#replace-with-upsert) in `replaceOne`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find use in the mongoose [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findOneAndUpdate()) method as it has an optional third parameter that lets you set an `upsert` boolean. Use it like so:

```
//...get the document you want to check exists, name it orig
// orig = {_id: 5a51b125c5500f5aa094c7bd, name: 'Bob', age: 50};
const opts = { new: true, upsert: true };
const newDoc = await documentModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: orig._id }, orig, opts);
```